Basis and dual basis in finite dimensional vector spaces
In finite dimension, a basis $\{f_i\}\in V$ and a dual basis $\{g_i\}\in V^*$ should satisfies $\langle f_i, g_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$.
I am wondering what is the terminology, if now I have a basis $(f_i)\in X\subset V$, and a dual basis  $(g_i)\in Y\subset V^* $ (That is, $(f_i)$ and  $(g_i)$ are not basis of $V$ and $V^*$ but of a subset of them), but I still have $\langle f_i, g_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$
Can I still call $(f_i)$ and  $(g_i)$ as dual basis of each other?  Since in this case, I can still represent:
$x\in X$ as $x=\sum_i  f_i \langle x, g_i \rangle$
and
$y\in Y$ as $y=\sum_i  g_i \langle x, f_i \rangle$

Sure: In your setting $(g_i)$ is a basis of the dual space $X^$, viewed as a subspace of $V^$, so it is the dual basis to $(f_i)$. (On an unrelated note: don't use < and > in TeX/MathJax for pairings, use \langle and \rangle instead: compare $<f_i, g_i>$ to $\langle f_i, g_i \rangle$. I've gone ahead and changed this for you here already.)

The simple answer is yes. If $ N = dim X \leq dim Y = M$, you can compute it then easy (for $x \in X$)
$$x = (x_1,x_2,\dots, x_N) = \sum_{i=1}^{N} x_i f_i =\sum_{i=1}^{N} \langle x,g_i \rangle f_i. $$
For the equation with $y \in Y$ you need $M \leq N$. So both equation holds, iff $N = M$.

Thanks for the answer,   I agree that the dimension of X and Y should be the same. And I am wondering is it OK if  $Y\ne X^$ and $X\ne Y^$?
